# Python - valor gravado no banco está zerado

Tags: mysql, python, banco-de-dados, arduino, raspberry-pi

Estou fazendo um trabalho para faculdade usando um arduino e um raspberry para fazer uma horta autônoma. Os sensores de temperatura e umidade, luminosidade e o higrômetro estão ligados ao arduino e estou fazendo a comunicação via serial (USB) para a leitura dos dados dos sensores no raspberry e a gravação em banco de dados. Os dados estão sendo lidos certinho só que a temperatura está gravando 0 no BD mas na saída do terminal com o print saí o valor da temperatura correta. Os outros 3 dados estão gravando corretamente.

Essa é a linha que grava em uma string os dados do sensores no Arduino

```
//Linha que envia os sinais do sensor via Serial para gravar no BD
  sinais = String(temperatura) + "," + String(umidade) + "," + String(luminosidade) + "," + String(leituraSensorSolo);
  Serial.println(sinais);
```

Esse é o script Python que estou usando para gravação no bd

```py
    import serial
    comport = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600) 
    print ('Serial Iniciada...\n')

    import mysql.connector
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='sinais')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    add_sinais = ("INSERT INTO sinais (sin_temp,sin_umid,sin_lum,sin_solo) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")

    while (True):
      serialValue = comport.readline()
      serialValue = str(serialValue)
      data_sinais = serialValue.split(",")  
      print (data_sinais)
      cursor.execute(add_sinais, data_sinais)
      cnx.commit()

    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
    comport.close()
```

Saída do terminal, o último 0 está correto pq é saída digital (0/1)

```
Serial Iniciada...

["b'22.80", '86.00', '1016', "0\\r\\n'"]
["b'22.70", '86.00', '1017', "0\\r\\n'"]
```

---

Edit: acredito que o problema esteja no "b" que está vindo antes do dado da temperatura, não sei pq aparece isso. Acredito que seja isso pq alterei o campo no bd para varchar e gravou no campo assim: b22.70.

Alguém sabe como tirar esse "b" ou pq ele está aparecendo

Comment: Parece que você está pegando os dados dos sensores de forma errada. Não tem nada a ver com o banco de dados, que está gravando o que você manda gravar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, meio que na gambiarra.
O "b" que está vindo a mais, quando converto os dados da serial para string, é uma identificação da própria biblioteca serial do python, que identificou os dados como bits.
Para resolver, depois de converter para string, utilizei a função de substring do python e gravei novamente na variável "serialValue", só acrescentei a linha:

```
serialValue = serialValue[2:]
```